# Karma: What does basePath get resolved to when it's an empty string?

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

The [docs](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/config/files.html) say:

> Pattern matching and basePath
>
> - All of the relative patterns will get resolved using the `basePath` first.
> - If the basePath is a relative path, it gets resolved to the directory where the configuration file is located.
> - Eventually, all the patterns will get resolved into files using glob, so you can use minimatch expressions like `test/unit/**/*.spec.js`.

This doesn't seem to address the case where:

```
basePath: ''
```

In that case, what would it get resolved to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An empty string is equivalent to a relative path of `.`. In other words, relative to right here.

Comment: I would think you mean "." not "/".  The former is what somewhat might call "right here", or "current directory" in more common parlance.  The latter is a very different thing.

Comment: I thought using `.` would be confusing as a filepath (for people not used to terminal), but you are correct. Probably should give *correct* answers over *easy* ones... I apologize.